# How to test ASP.NET Core 1.1 with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 with an Entity Framework (code first) web app.
I want to do TDD (test driven development), I've tried several times to make a test project, but I've failed. Also searched for 2 hours on Google (and here).

I want to test controllers and view models of my web app, but I'm not able to pass `DbContext`, so how can I create and seed a `DbContext` for my tests and also manage users and sessions?

Comment: ty, I'm not English, so typos are common for me

Comment: Look at the test folder of this project. It should give you enough information to get started. https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore

Comment: Can you please show us how you set up dependency injection for your data repository. If you followed the guidelines on the asp.net core website you should be able to mock a data repository skipping the DbContext.